# Delete all tags with specific text inside in both jQuery & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out how to remove all of the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` instances from the html below in both JavaScript and jQuery:

```
<div id='test'>
<p>some text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

The closest I could come to was:

```
$('#test').html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''); // only removes &nbsp; but not tags
```

How can I:
1. Select all tags with   in? (in both JS & JQ)
2. And delete?
(presumably like this, but couldn't test as couldn't do 1 above: JQ: el.remove(); JS: el.parentNode.removeChild(el))

I've also tried the following but to no avail:

```
$('<p>&nbsp;</p>').replaceAll(''); // fails
$('#test').html().replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>',''); // partially fails
$('#test').html().replace(/<p>&nbsp;</p>/gi,''); // fails
$("p:contains('&nbsp;')").replace('') // fails
$("p:contains('&nbsp;')").replaceWith(''); // fails
$("p:contains('&nbsp;')").remove() // fails?
// fails
var toRemove = $("p:contains('&nbsp;')");
$('#test').remove(toRemove);
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I'm curious to know why. Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Select all `p`s, check the trimmed content of each, and if empty, remove that paragraph.

Comment: A quick, dirty and IE 9+ solution: `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("p")).forEach(function(p) { if(p.innerHTML == "&nbsp;") p.parentNode.removeChild(p) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your logic is because `:contains()` uses the text content of the element which is HTML encoded, therefore `&nbsp;` is read as a single space, not the entity you're looking for.

Your use of `html().replace()` is also flawed as you're working on the returned HTML string but not doing anything with the value, and also `html()` will only retrieve the content of the first element within the collection.

To make this work as you require you can use `filter()` and search for the `html()` which matches `&nbsp;`, like this:

```js
$('p').filter(function() {
  return $(this).html().trim() == '&nbsp;';
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`contains` only works for the text content of the node, not its innerHTML.

You can just filter them by their contents, and then use `remove()`:

```js
$('p').filter(function() { return $.trim($(this).html()) == '&nbsp;' }).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$("p").html(function (i,html) {

    if(!html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''))
    {
    $(this).remove();
    }
})
```

You can refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0n3m5x6h/4/).